# What's the difference between a normal method and a setter method in Dart?

Tags: dart, methods, setter

I just stared learning Dart yesterday. I want to know what's the difference between a normal method and a setter method in Dart? For example, I have the following demo code.

```
class Person {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;

  // Normal method
  fullName(String? name) {
    var names = name!.split(' ');
    this.firstName = names[0];
    this.lastName = names[1];
  }
}

main() {
  Person p = Person();
  p.fullName('John Smith');
  print("${p.firstName} ${p.lastName}");
}
```

And:

```
class Person {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;

  // Setter
  set fullName(String? name) {
    var names = name!.split(' ');
    this.firstName = names[0];
    this.lastName = names[1];
  }
}

main() {
  Person p = Person();
  p.fullName = 'John Smith';
  print("${p.firstName} ${p.lastName}");
}
```

The difference seems only the invocation syntax. Besides that, are there any other differences?

Comment: It can be paired with a `get`. Although perhaps that’s “just syntax” as well..

Comment: With a setter, you are limited to taking only one positional argument, and it can only return `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly comes down to conventions.

Generally you wouldn't want a setter without a getter. (Although getters without setters are fine...and common.)

In your case, I'd use a setter – and just add a getter!

(Although I'd add more checking to the setter to make sure someone doesn't pass in `"A string with more spaces!"`).

Answer (score 1):

with a setter, you will not need parenthesis to pass in a value as param. instead, you will use an equal sign. And the other thing with setter is that the return type of getter should be the same as the param type of setter.

```
class User{
 late _age; 

 get age(){
  return _age;
 }

 set age(int age){
  _age = age;
 }
}

void main(){
 var user = User();
 user.age = 4; 

 print("age is ${user.age}");
}
```